# CodeBlocks Debugger Doesn't Work in Linux

Tags: c, debugging, codeblocks

This is the full debugger log of a brand new "hello world" program i've just created to show that it doesn't work.
Works if i run it directly from my command line, but somehow not inside my codeblocks :(

Need help with making it work inside codeblocks please.

```
#include <stdio.h>
  
int main()
{
  
    printf("Hello World");
  
    return 0;
}

-------------------------------------------------------------

Active debugger config: GDB/CDB debugger:Default
Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Selecting target: 
Debug
Adding source dir: /home/gaezvr/Desktop/j/
Adding source dir: /home/gaezvr/Desktop/j/
Adding file: /home/gaezvr/Desktop/j/bin/Debug/j
Changing directory to: /home/gaezvr/Desktop/j/.
Set variable: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:

[debug]Command-line: /usr/bin/gdb -nx -fullname -quiet  -args /home/gaezvr/Desktop/j/bin/Debug/j
[debug]Working dir : /home/gaezvr/Desktop/j

Starting debugger: /usr/bin/gdb -nx -fullname -quiet  -args /home/gaezvr/Desktop/j/bin/Debug/j
Setting SHELL to '/bin/sh'
done

[debug]Reading symbols from /home/gaezvr/Desktop/j/bin/Debug/j...
[debug](gdb) 
[debug]> set prompt >>>>>>cb_gdb:

Setting breakpoints

[debug]Using terminal's PID as console PID 7991, TTY /dev/?
[debug]Queued:[tty /dev/?]
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> show version
[debug]GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1
[debug]Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
[debug]License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
[debug]This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
[debug]There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
[debug]Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
[debug]This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
[debug]Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
[debug]For bug reporting instructions, please see:
[debug]<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
[debug]Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
[debug]    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
[debug]For help, type "help".
[debug]Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set confirm off

Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1

[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set width 0
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set height 0
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set breakpoint pending on
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set print asm-demangle on
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set unwindonsignal on
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set print elements 200
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set disassembly-flavor intel
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> catch throw
[debug]Catchpoint 1 (throw)
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> directory /home/gaezvr/Desktop/j/
[debug]Source directories searched: /home/gaezvr/Desktop/j:$cdir:$cwd
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> tty /dev/?
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> run
[debug]/dev/?: No such file or directory.
[debug]During startup program exited with code 1.
[debug]Starting program: /home/gaezvr/Desktop/j/bin/Debug/j 
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:

During startup program exited with code 1.

[debug]> quit

Debugger finished with status 0

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
Not using WSL as of I know.
```

This is the code im running LOL, whichever the program is, it just happens the same, I dont even know why, as you said there some weird exit that occurs, but cant figure out why, could it be codeblocks permissions ?

[Image Of Terminal Pops Up When I Try To Debug My Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLpVD.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the [mre]. -- BTW, the debugger works apparently, the log shows the commands and outputs. _Your program_ terminates with exit code 1.

Comment: It doesn't, its the default C hello world example, look at the **MRE** at the top, thanks for your response anyway @thebusybee

Comment: @thebusybee Actually, a tab opens when I Debug, but it just doesnt show absolutely anything:  (See Image Ill Attach)

Comment: The command `tty /dev/?` looks strange, and this results in the error message `/dev/?: No such file or directory.`. Did you configure anything related to a terminal? What Linux distribution and version do you use? Are you using WSL? Please [edit] your question to provide requested information or clarification.

Comment: @Bodo i've updated my post with the info, however i've found the problem, its that i'm using gnome terminal, however when i change to xterm terminal, it works. Is it possible to make it work for gnome?

Comment: The information about the different terminal applications and how you chose between these belongs into the question and ideally into the title.